# fail to compile with SDL: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, sdl-2

I'm trying to compile using SDL2 library with no success.

```
OS: MacOS 10.13.2
Visual Studio Code 1.43.1
Language: c++
```

I'm using the Lazy Foo's very basic example code.
This is the message I recieve:

```
[Running] cd "/Users/martinjoselizondocolomes/Programacion/01_hello_SDL/" && g++ 01_hello_SDL.cpp -o 01_hello_SDL && "/Users/martinjoselizondocolomes/Programacion/01_hello_SDL/"01_hello_SDL
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_CreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in 01_hello_SDL-a16d96.o
  "_SDL_Delay", referenced from:
      _main in 01_hello_SDL-a16d96.o
  "_SDL_DestroyWindow", referenced from:
      _main in 01_hello_SDL-a16d96.o
  "_SDL_FillRect", referenced from:
      _main in 01_hello_SDL-a16d96.o
  "_SDL_GetError", referenced from:
      _main in 01_hello_SDL-a16d96.o
  "_SDL_GetWindowSurface", referenced from:
      _main in 01_hello_SDL-a16d96.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in 01_hello_SDL-a16d96.o
  "_SDL_MapRGB", referenced from:
      _main in 01_hello_SDL-a16d96.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      _main in 01_hello_SDL-a16d96.o
  "_SDL_UpdateWindowSurface", referenced from:
      _main in 01_hello_SDL-a16d96.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.168 seconds
```

Comment: Looks like you need to link with the sdl library.

Comment: how can I do that? can you be more sepecific? I'm new here

Answer (score 1):

Building C++ code requires three stages:

**Preprocessor** deals with macros and `#include` directives, so your header files are required at this step.

**Compiler** generates object files.  This is the point when the syntax is checked in your source files.

**Linker** combines object files and libraries into an executable so your runtime libraries must be available and specified to the linker.

For g++, you specify libraries by giving their full name on the command line or use the `-l` shortcut which figures out the proper prefix (lib) and suffix.  So in your case I believe you can add `-lSDL`.

EDIT: If that doesn't work, check the output of

```
sdl-config --libs
```

Comment: I recieve this error (I've tried with different names -lSDL -lSDL2): "library not found for -lSDL2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1"